# R: Filter rows with set number of values for each column

Tags: r, dataframe, split, subset

I have a very large dataframe containing 2 important columns that have values of interest, currently separated by commas.

For instance:

```
ID    Data1      Data2
1     12,5,6     1
2     3, 4       
3     70, 20     10
4     80         35, 40, 30
5     50, 15     90
```

"12, 5, 6" is read as one character in R.

I need to subset the data to only obtain rows that have 2 values for 'Data1' and 1 value for 'Data2'. From this example, ID 3 and 5 would be filtered.

Does anyone have a good suggestion for going about this?

I thought about using tidyr's 'separate' function to sort through the columns individually and separate by commas, but that would involve a lot of complicated back-and-forth and then I would need to combine them at the end with the corresponding IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe not straightforward but should work :

```
library(dplyr)

data = data %>% filter((Data1!="") & (Data2!=""))%>%
  subset( (str_count(Data1, pattern=",")==1) & (str_count(Data2, pattern=","))==0)
```

First I delete rows with empty data and then I subset those that have 1 comma in Data 1 (corresponding to 2 numbers) and those that have 0 comma in Data 2 (corresponding to 1 number)

Comment: You can put everything inside your `filter`-function: `filter(str_count(Data1, ",") == 1, str_count(Data2, ",") == 0, !is.na(Data1), !is.na(Data2))` or a similar expression should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string on comma and count the lengths.

```
result <- subset(df, lengths(strsplit(Data1, ',\\s*')) == 2 & 
                     lengths(strsplit(Data2, ',\\s*')) == 1)
result

#  ID Data1 Data2
#3  3 70,20    10
#5  5 50,15    90
```

Answer (score 0):

We can remove the characters others than `,` in columns 'Data1', 'Data1', get the count of `,` with `nchar` to construct to a logical vector for `subset`ting

```
subset(data, nchar(gsub("[^,]+", "", Data1)) == 1 &
      nchar(gsub("[^,]+", "", Data2)) == 0)
```

-output

```
 ID  Data1 Data2
3  3 70, 20    10
5  5 50, 15    90
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, Data1 = c("12,5,6", "3, 4", "70, 20", 
"80", "50, 15"), Data2 = c("1", NA, "10", "35, 40, 30", "90")), 
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```